# How to configure jenkins slave using Amazon ECS plugin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecs, jenkins-agent

I have have created two clusters ECS in the same subnetwork, one for jenkins master and other for jenkins slave(empty cluster). I have installed Amazon ECS plugin on jenkins master but I am not able to configure jenkins slave node. I created both clusters using ecs-cli up command and following are my settings for Amazon ECS plugin similar to my cluster. After running this job a task definition is created in ECS but the service and task definition are not created in the cluster.

Name: ecs-jenkins-slave

Amazon ECS Credential: aws_credentials

ECS Region Name: cluster_region

ECS Clutser: cluster_cluster

ECS Agent Template

Label: ecs-jenkins-slave

Docker Image: jenkinsci/jnlp-slave

Subnet: cluster_subnet

security_group: cluster_sg

(rest of the fields are default)

I created a test job to verify configuration and under **Restrict where this project can be run of my test job**, I am getting *Label ecs-jenkins-slave is serviced by no nodes and 1 cloud. Permissions or other restrictions provided by plugins may prevent this job from running on those nodes* message. When I am running the job, it is going in pending state with message *'(pending—‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘ecs-jenkins-slave’) '*